# How to create an instance of a class that have a constructor with a service injected and configured in the main in .net 7.0 with activator

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-7.0, activator

I will try to be very clear.

I am writing a Queue Azure Function in `.net7`.

I have some `Managers` that implements an interface. I know which manager instanciate only when a new message arrive.
My managers have only one constructor with an interface in input:

```
internal class MyNotificationManager : INotificationManager
{
    public MyNotificationManager(IContext context)
    { ... }

      ...
}
```

Here my `Main`, where I configure all my services:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string connectionString = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DatabaseConnectionString");

    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(s =>
        {
            s.AddTransient<IContext, MyDBContext>(c => new MyDBContext(connectionString));
            s.AddTransient<INotificationManagerResolver, NotificationManagerResolver>();
            ...
        })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

The `NotificationManagerResolver` that you see above creates the instance of one of my mager. Here the implementation:

```
internal class NotificationManagerResolver : INotificationManagerResolver
{
    public INotificationManager Resolve(string notificationType)
    {
        ...

        var type = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(NotificationManagerResolver))
                           .GetType(concreteType);
            
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        return instance as INotificationManager;
    }
}
```

In the function, I try to resolve the manager:

```
    private readonly INotificationManagerResolver _notificationManagerResolver;

    ...

    [Function("MyFunction")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%QueueName%", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] string queueItem)
    {
        var notificationManager = _notificationManagerResolver.Resolve(c.NotificationType);
    }
```

Obviously I get an error when I try to resolve and instanciate my manager, because it does not know how resolve the `IContext` in input in the constructor of the manager, even though I defined the mapping in the  `Main`.

I can easily resolve the problem removing the line

`s.AddTransient<IContext, MyDBContext>(c => new MyDBContext(connectionString));`

from the `Main` and modifying the resolver. If I change the line

`var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);`

with this line

`var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new MyDBContext(connectionString));`

everything works correctly.

But I don't like the solution. I do not want to bind the resolver to the definition of `IContext`.

Any suggestion please?

Thank you

Comment: How would you instantiate it without an instance of IContext? Think about it in terms of normal object instantiation and then you'll realize that what you're trying to do with reflection simply doesn't make sense. In addition, this is an anti-pattern for several reasons. You're using a form of a service locator (except without optimizations or safeguards) and you're leaving yourself open to all sorts of issues/attacks if the NotificationType isn't supported by your assembly since you don't check a whitelist. You should rethink your architecture if possible.

Comment: Also, the fact that you've registered your context doesn't matter because Activator.CreateInstance isn't wired into your DI container.

Comment: Why not to register all your `INotificationManager` implementations in DI container (not as interface, but as a exact implementation type)? And then in the resolver you will just ask the DI container to instantiate the desired manager for you with `IContext` dependency automatic resolution.

Comment: @DavidLHi, thank you for the answer. About the 1st comment: I haven’t copied all the code. The purpose it’s exactly what you explained: Leave myself open to all sort of NotificationType, even to the one I don’t know in this moment. However, if it cannot activate any instance, it simply should return a null and then exit the azure function. I don’t want a whitelist because the notificationType is highly “exchangeable“ and I simply want to add/remove a .DLL from the function when I need a change, without modify a code. However, I appreciate if you can give me suggestions to improve my solution.

Comment: @DavidL for the 2nd message, yes it is exactly the problem I have but that I would like to resolve. I don’t think mine is an elegant solution and I would like to change it. I used this guide, the third solution: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/dependency-injection-on-azure-functions-5-ways-selecting/ba-p/1502394

Comment: @Serg I explained better why I adopted this solution in a comment above. Thank you

Comment: So, you do not want explicit white list of `INotificationManager` implementations, but you still can scan the assembly for *all* of interface implementations at startup and then register them all in DI-container, is not  it? In this case you will able just replace assembly and a type list will be changed without any changes into registration code.

Comment: @Serg thank you. I am trying to implement the example number 5 in the link I added in the comment before. I am doing a foreach loop as you suggested to me and I am creating an implicit delegate. But for some reason it does not work. I am investigating. In a second step I will divide assemblies in some way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to register all existing implementation of `INotificationManager` without explicitly listing all its types in the code, you can perform the assembly scan and find all implementations at runtime.
Then use DI container to resolve the exact implementation you need.
To do so:

1. Add `scrutor` nuget-package to support assembly scan capabilities.
2. Modify your registration code in the following way scan assembly, containing the `NotificationManagerResolver` type for types that implements `INotificationManager` interface

   ```
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(s =>
        {
            s.AddTransient<IContext, MyDBContext>(c => new MyDBContext(connectionString));
            s.AddTransient<INotificationManagerResolver, NotificationManagerResolver>();
            s.Scan(scan => scan.FromAssemblyOf<NotificationManagerResolver>()
                .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<INotificationManager>())
                .AsSelf()
                .WithTransientLifetime());


        })
        .Build();
   ```
3. Modify `NotificationManagerResolver` to get service provider as dependency and then use it to resolve managers

   ```
    public class NotificationManagerResolver : INotificationManagerResolver
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

        public NotificationManagerResolver(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
        }

        public INotificationManager? Resolve(string notificationType)
        {
            var concreteType = GetManagerTypeForNotification(notificationType);
            return _provider.GetService(concreteType) as INotificationManager;
        }
    }
   ```